# WordPress - Filter by Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom taxonomy using Custom Post Type UI. How can I get this taxonomy to available in the sidebar/ widgets so that I can sort by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to look into [Creating your own Widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), or hardcoding into your sidebar your own [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to filter and sort according to whatever criteria you need.